# Save image from URL using PHP (saves in 0KB file size)

Tags: php, image, image-processing, curl

**What I'm trying to do:**

`file_get_contents()` an online image, then **save** it to a directory on my server, with a new filename. 
The save path / directory is ***writable***. CHMOD permissions: **777**

---

**What I've tried:**

- `file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents($image_url));`  **// SAVES 0KB IMAGE**
- `copy($image_url,$filepath);`  **// SAVES 0KB IMAGE**
- cURL   **// SAVES 0KB IMAGE**

So I'm already getting confused why none of this is working, when it should be...

---

**Here are the relevant values inside my PHPinfo:**

> ```
> allow_url_fopen = On  
> allow_url_include = On  
> open_basedir = no value  
>
> post_max_size = 8M  
> upload_max_filesize = 50M  
> upload_tmp_dir = no value  
>
> max_execution_time = 18000  
> max_file_uploads = 20  
> max_input_nesting_level = 64  
> max_input_time = 60  
> max_input_vars = 1000  
> memory_limit = 256M
> ```

---

And here is my full **PHP code** (I'm now using a function to save the image, because *I'm just about desperate enough to try anything*):

```php
function save_image($inPath,$outPath)
{ // Download images from remote server
    $in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
    $out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
    while ($chunk = fread($in,8388608))
    {
        fwrite($out, $chunk, 8388608);
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}

// THE ORIGINAL IMAGE TO GET
$image_url = 'http://m1.i.pbase.com/u38/antidote3/upload/31848351.Cute.jpg';

// THE IMAGE EXTENSION
$image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1);

// THE NEW FILE NAME
$filename   = 'product5_'. md5($image_url . $sku).'.'.$image_type;

// THE SAVE PATH
// OUTPUT: /var/www/site/media/catalog/product/FILE_NAME.FILE_TYPE
$filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog'. DS . 'product'. DS . $filename;

// SAVE THIS BIATCH!
save_image($image_url, $filepath);

// OTHER SAVE METHODS
// file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents($image_url));
// copy($image_url,$filepath);
```

---

Running `strlen(file_get_contents($image_url))` on the image returns a big fat `0`.
But shouldn't it work with the following enabled on my server?

> ```
> allow_url_fopen = On  
> allow_url_include = On
> ```

Apparently, the problem doesn't lie on the *writing*, but `file_get_contents($image_url)` doesn't have anything inside it.

Any ideas why? Thanks!

---

**Other Information:**

- Platform: **Magento**
- Language: **PHP**
- PHP Version: **5.4.6**

Comment: Try using `":"` instead of `"."` in `$image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1);`, from what I could tell from the PHP manual (example #1) http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: is there a reason you dont just save the URL link to the database, and hotlink?

Comment: @Fred thanks for the input, thing is the function was my last resort, but even using the `copy()` / `file_put_contents()` or cURL methods beforehand it had always returned the same 0KB result. Anyway, I've now upped the function to save up to `8388608 kb` just to get it out of the way. :)

Comment: did you verify the length of file_get_contents($image_url) to make sure you are getting something from the file_contents call... just sayin everyone is focusing on the write... have you looked at the read?

Comment: I was able to do it with the http://m1.i.pbase.com/u38/antidote3/upload/31848351.Cute.jpg link using file_get/put_contents with no issue. Have you confirmed that the  fopen url wrappers are enabled on your host

Comment: @Fred : Yes I am using `Magento` and @Orangepill : Yes, I've posted it on my original post `allow_url_fopen = On` (as well as other revelant php.ini values). Thanks. Tried the 2 answers (below) so far, but none has worked...

Comment: @KyleKoopman : hot-linking is not the ideal scenario, we would like to host the images ourselves so as not to make the content dependent on the original source, as well as not to use-up other people's bandwidth/server resources. Thanks.

Comment: @Orangepill : Hold up, I just ran `strlen(file_get_contents($image_url))` on the image, and it returned **0**. But shouldn't it work with these enabled? `allow_url_fopen = On` & `allow_url_include = On` ... My brain is literally aching now.

Comment: You do not want to enable `allow_url_include = on` for security reasons. Disable it! Otherwise you can be targeted to remote code inclusion attacks if any of your code is insecurely including other code. It is easier for an attacker to put his code on a server and include it from there than first have to upload it somehow to your server and include it via filesystem.

Comment: @Sven : I've now turned `allow_url_include` **off**. Still, I'm faced with the dilemma of getting this to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any security extentions like suhosin running on your server? The image server might also be configured to not like the standard PHP request headers and refuse to deliver content exactly to prevent automated scripts from grabbing their content. I believe you have written permission to get these images onto your server - have you contacted the other administrator for help?

Comment: @Sven : "Any security extentions like suhosin running on your server?" - `Suhosin` does not show on the **PHPinfo** file, so that is probably a no. I tried saving images with image URLs hosted on our server (different domains, etc), and I was able to save them all successfully! So, I am only able to *"get"* files on our server, do you know how I'd be able to bypass this (considering what I've already tried that have not worked). Thanks!

Comment: Then it probably is a security measure of your own hoster that prevents PHP scripts from getting anything via HTTP. You have to talk to them about this.

Comment: I was able to get it via file_get_content without doing anything goofy. Since she's getting the same results via curl and fopen I would guess the issue is a firewall rule. @Love if you have shell access on the machine try doing a wget from the command line. Also make sure on the php script you have errors display errors and error reporting enabled.

Comment: another test would be to try testing the process by pulling from other servers including itself.

Comment: Sven & @Orangepill : You guys were right, it was server-related (a firewall rule). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **a firewall rule on the server** was causing it. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try something like this (using feof and fread the right way!) - I also changed how you are grabbing the extension:

```
<?php
function save_image($inPath, $outPath) {
  $in  = fopen($inPath,  "rb");
  $out = fopen($outPath, "wb");

  while (!feof($in)) {
    $read = fread($in, 8192);
    fwrite($out, $read);
  }

  fclose($in);
  fclose($out);
}

// THE ORIGINAL IMAGE TO GET
$image_url = 'http://m1.i.pbase.com/u38/antidote3/upload/31848351.Cute.jpg';

// THE IMAGE EXTENSION
$image_type = end(explode(".", $image_url));

// THE NEW FILE NAME
$filename   = 'product5_'. md5($image_url . $sku).'.'.$image_type;

// THE SAVE PATH
// OUTPUT: /var/www/site/media/catalog/product/FILE_NAME.FILE_TYPE
$filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog'. DS . 'product'. DS . $filename;

// SAVE THIS BIATCH!
save_image($image_url, $filepath);
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. I definitely tried the method more than once & it put the upload into what seemed like an infinite loop (the page would not successfully load, but the browser seemed like it was about to) in all instances. Not sure why such a reaction would be triggered...

Comment: Updated my code to use `end(explode(".", $image_url));`, +1 for you.

Comment: I tested this code and it worked fine for me. The issue remains elsewhere at this point, possibly server-side. Try checking `phpinfo()` to ensure url opening is allowed/enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure will it help. Can you try this way?

```
function save_image($inPath,$outPath) {
  $inbuf = file_get_contents($inPath);
  $fp = fopen($outPath,'w');
  fwrite($fp,$inbuf);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

note: it was a typo, $buf intead of $inbuf.

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately the modifications didn't change anything. 0KB on the saved images just the same.

Comment: can you try again, change $buf to $inbuf?

Comment: Still no luck, same outcom. Thanks!